# Mystery Ceramic Electrical Component

Tags: electrical

This may be a bit off the beaten path, but these were recently found by a previous coworker at a jobsite from a building that was built in the 1920's in the Midwest United States. They exactly fit an electrical junction box and were found in a service closet.

Any ideas what these may be?

[image: Side 1]

[image: Side 2]

Comment: Looks like a cover to me, just vented.  Ceramic is a good insulator (in the heat sense in this case), so I suspect the holes and channels are intended to permit airflow.

Comment: Based on the age and other things in the building I was thinking something like a knob and tube junction box/converter, or even something like low voltage distribution, etc.

Comment: I agree with @brownRedHawk although I have never found one with this many holes. +

Comment: I suggest asking at [/r/whatisthis](http://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthis) and [/r/whatisthisthing](http://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing).

Comment: @ArgentoSapiens Thank you for the suggestion. It's hard to remember how many SE's there are!

Comment: If you find out, please let us know!